# Unable to mention path to config file with os.execl()

Tags: python

*Here is the code I am trying to execute:*

```
os.execl('executable','--configurations', 'path-to-conf-file')
```

The path-to-conf-file does not get honored. I've also tried

```
os.execl('executables','--configurations path-to-conf-file')
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

*Perhaps, you need to change it to:*

```
os.execl(sys.executables,'--configurations','path-to-conf-file')
```